# disable output escaping="yes" not working with current() funcation

Tags: xml, xslt

In my xslt disable-output-escaping="yes" is not working for current function.

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="current()" />
```

is not working. it is not converting  br tag from xml to br into HTML.
any thoughts on this.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of your XML, and the output you expect. Also, you should probably show more of your XSLT too to (such as the template match) as if you are using `current()` then the node you are currently matching is all important. Thank you.

Comment: If your XML has `br` elements and you want to copy them through to your HTML result you should simply be able to use `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`. If your XML has escaped HTML markup then it might be that using `disable-output-escaping` works, but only if you serialize the result, which some XSLT processors (notable the one in Mozilla browsers like Firefox) don't do or which might not be done at all if you for instance use your construct inside of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons disable-output-escaping might not work; the most usual is that your transformation output isn't being sent straight to a serializer, which means there is no escaping process to be disabled.

`disable-output-escaping` is almost invariably a nasty hack; there is usually a better way of doing it, and if you share with us what you are trying to achieve then we might be able to suggest it.

You say "it is not converting br tag from xml to br into HTML" but that's not what disable-output-escaping is supposed to do. If your original source XML contained a br tag, then the XDM node tree will contain a br element node, and `xsl:value-of` will ignore this element node whether or not you disable escaping. Perhaps you simply want to use `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:value-of`.

(If you showed us your requirements and not only your code then it would be easier to help you.)